# how to split a string by chunks of 2 characters using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, reduce

I am trying to use reduce to get the following output:

```
solution('abcdef') // should return ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

if the length of the string is odd we should convert it into even and add a '_'(underscore)

```
solution('abc') // should return ['ab', 'c_']
```

here is where I am so far:

1. my if function is not working, not really sure why.
2. I only get till 2 strings but cant go beyond those. I think I am forcing the result to become what I want but this wont work in case we only have 1 character or 2 right?

```js
function solution(str){
 if (str.lenght % 2!==0){str.concat('_')};
 console.log(str)
 const array =  str.split(',');
 
  const reducer = array.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr)=>{
    return [...acc, curr[i]+curr[i+1], curr[i+2]+curr[i+3]]
  },[])
  
  return reducer
}

solution('helloworl')
```

any hints and recommendations on how to face the problem would be nice!
thanks a lot

Comment: using reduce function shall make things more complicated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```js
let splitTwos = (str) => str.match(/\w{1,2}/g).map(e => e.length == 2?e:e+"_")

console.log(splitTwos("abcde"))
console.log(splitTwos("abcdef"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alan Omars answer is probably a better way to handle this, but if you insist on using array reduce you could do it like this. Convert Your string to an array of single characters and use reduce like this.

I would not recommend this, but it answers your question.

```
function solution(str){
    if (str.length % 2 !== 0){
        str = str.concat('_');
    };

    const arrayOfChars =  str.split('');
 
    const reducer = arrayOfChars.reduce(
        (acc, curr, i, arr) => {
            if(i % 2 !== 0){
                acc[acc.length - 1] = acc[acc.length - 1] + curr;
                return acc;
            }

            return [...acc, curr];
        },
        []
    );
  
    return reducer;
}

solution('helloworl');
```

Comment: this one is great but checking, still doesnt deal with the odd or even lenghts of the string to add the underscore, it adds it in both cases. Thanks though for the thinking on the actuall reduce, helps a lot seeing implementations from others

Comment: Same as with the other answer, I also misspelled length. I think We both copied your typo

Answer (score 1):

I also think using match will be better, since you asked for reduce, here is my implementation

```
function solution(str){
    if (str.length % 2 !==0){
        str+='_';
    }

    const strarray =  str.split('');
    temp='';
    let res = strarray.reduce((acc,cur,i,arr)=>{
        if(i%2 === 0){
            temp+=arr[i];
            temp+=arr[i+1];
            acc.push(temp)
        }
        temp='';
        return acc;
    },[]);
    return res;
}
console.log(solution('helloworl'));
```

Comment: Yes, agree that the match solution is amazing. I actually used it while thinking through the problem but wasn't able to add the underscore :(. Thanks a lot for your help but just as the previous proposal I think it is not quite dealing with the underscore on even or odd length, but I loved the way you solved the reduce function. It is super clear!. I am a beginner and get really stuck in the thinking of the solutions.

Comment: Glad to be helpful, it should work, I misspelled 'length' !